# pyspark: hours diff between two dates columns

Tags: pyspark, datediff

I would like to calculate number of hours between two date columns in pyspark.
Could only find how to calculate number of days between the dates.

```
dfs_4.show()


+--------------------+--------------------+
|        request_time|            max_time|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|2017-11-17 00:18:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:07:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:35:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:10:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:03:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:45:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:35:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:59:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:28:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:11:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:13:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:42:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:07:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:40:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:15:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:05:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:50:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:40:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:25:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
|2017-11-17 00:35:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Calculation of number of days :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
dfs_5 = dfs_4.withColumn('date_diff', F.datediff(F.to_date(dfs_4.max_time), F.to_date(dfs_4.request_time)))

dfs_5.show()

+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|        request_time|            max_time|date_diff|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|2017-11-17 00:18:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:07:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:35:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:10:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:03:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:45:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:35:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:59:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:28:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:11:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:13:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:42:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:07:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:40:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:15:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:05:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:50:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:40:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:25:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
|2017-11-17 00:35:...|2017-11-20 23:59:...|        3|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

How can I do the same for hours ? 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [hour](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hour) to extract the hour from your date time field and simply subtract them to a new column. Now there is a case that the time difference is over a day and you need to add the whole days in between. So I would create the column days _diff as you did and then try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dfs_5 = dfs_4.withColumn('hours_diff', (dfs_4.date_diff*24) + 
                          F.hour(dfs_4.max_time) - F.hour(dfs_4.request_time))
```

Comment: Glad I could help You should vote up also if It was a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

One can use unix timestamp and calculate difference in seconds. after that convert to desired unit.

```
   dfs_5 = dfs_4.withColumn(
      'diff_in_seconds', 
      F.unix_timestamp(F.to_date(dfs_4.max_time) - F.unix_timestamp(F.to_date(dfs_4.request_time))
   )

   dfs_6 = dfs_4.withColumn(
      'diff_in_minutes', 
      F.round(
         (F.unix_timestamp(F.to_date(dfs_4.max_time) - F.unix_timestamp(F.to_date(dfs_4.request_time)))/60
      )
   )
```